# jquery mobile Popup Issue

Tags: cordova

I am getting an issue in jQuery mobile pop up while testing in android device (micromax)

I had created the pop up code in html page and  opened the pop up in js 
for the first time while opening the pop up we getting it correctly but after closing and reopened the same pop up we are getting the issue the close icon in the pop up is missing.

JS code to open the pop up

```
$("#popupAllPicked").popup({ history: false });

$("#popupAllPicked").popup("open");
```

JS code to close the pop up

```
$("#popupAllPicked").popup({ history: false });

$("#popupAllPicked").popup("close");
```

HTML code

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupAllPicked" class="ui-content popupBoundAllPicked" >
    <a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-a ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">Close</a>
    <center> </br>
        <p id="quantityName"></p><!--Beaf Back Ribs--></br>
        <div id="SKUNumberDiv">
            <input type="text" name="SKUNumber" value="" id="SKUNumber" placeholder="Enter SKU Number"></br>
        </div>
        <input type="number" name="Quantity" value="" id="quantity" placeholder="Enter Quantity"  ></br>
         <span id="quantityValue">  </span></br>
         <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-mini" onclick="closePopUpAllPicked();" style="background-color:#EB7D3C; text-decoration:none !important; text-shadow:none !important;font-size:15px; ">All Picked</a>
     </center>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you realy need jQuery for that? Cordova released a plugin for that, it's called dialogs. The Plugin is able to display simple Messages you can also get, which button the user has clicked (e.g. "Ok" or "Abort").

If you realy need jQuery for that it would be great to see the expected behavior. Maybe in a Demo or in a fiddle.

If you would like to use the Dialogs Plugin, feel free to install it via GitHub with `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs` a detailed guide and information can be found over here -> [Cordova Dialogs Plugin - Documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs)

Last but not least - a working example for you:

```
function alertDismissed() {
    // do something
}

navigator.notification.alert(
    'You are the winner!',  // message
    alertDismissed,         // callback
    'Game Over',            // title
    'Done'                  // buttonName
);
```

So i hope i helped you. Let me know if you need further information!

Comment: yes i also searched that too...since i want to set  color for that button...if it possible to do that....and more offen same kind of coding used  for other pop up's too

Comment: hm okay, afaik it's not possible to configure the layout from the dialogs shown from the plugin i told you. sorry for that sabarish!

Comment: hmmm okay that right .....did you know any solutions for the regarding pop up issue.....